# insserv: warning: script 'uwsgi' missing LSB tags and overrides

Tags: linux, debian, bash, shell, init.d

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
daemon="$APPVENV/bin/uwsgi"
args="--emperor $APPCONF/uwsgi/app.ini"
pid="$APPDIR/emperor.pid"
case "\$1" in
    start)
        echo "Starting uwsgi"
        start-stop-daemon -m -p \$pid --start --exec \$daemon -- \$args
        ;;
    stop)
        echo "Stopping script uwsgi"
        start-stop-daemon --signal INT -p \$pid --stop \$daemon -- \$args
        ;;
    reload)
        echo "Reloading conf"
        kill -HUP \$(< \$pid)
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/uwsgi {start|stop|reload}"
        exit 1
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

When I try to use it, it says I'm missing LSB tags and overrides. I googles it and found this as an example:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          scriptname
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO
```

I'm confused though, about firstly the remote_fs and syslog variables, is this something I need to keep as default? Secondly, how so I know what numbers I should be putting for default start and stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $remote_fs (and the $syslog)is used to tell that the script needs the remote file systems must be started before the current script is executed.
Unless your script needs it (which seems unlikely) you can remove the $remote_fs part. You should keep the $syslog though. You can also look [here](https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts) to have a better understanding of what you can / should use.

As for the numbers you see, these are the run levels where you script is to be called (either at startup, reboot, or shutdown). Some useful information are available [here](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/runlevels.htm). The defaults should be fine most of the time.

Comment: The link to debianhelp is 404'ing for me.

Comment: From Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20171017161304/http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/runlevels.htm